# Restricting dataset types does not work correctly in a dataset iterator

Tags: arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, iterator

I need to obtain a list of all the CAD drawings within a specified folder (and subfolders). I initially tried using a `Files Iterator` in ModelBuilder, but when I specified the extension, it prompted me to use the `Dataset Iterator` as the CAD extensions are recognised datasets.

After creating a test folder of four CAD files and a subfolder with one CAD file, I ran the model with a `Collect Value` to get the list of the full pathname for each file.

[image]

It ran for about a minute before "completing" the model without advancing to collect the values. As I had restricted the dataset type, this meant that it did not find any CAD files. I then removed the restriction and ran it again. This time it quickly returned the CAD files.

I then restricted the dataset type to `FEATURE`. It returned a list of the CAD files, when it should not have returned anything. Does the dataset iterator not recognise CAD files properly (whereas the files iterator does, and therefore does not allow me to use it)?

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/133688)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem with the dataset iterator is, but you can replace it with a little Python.

If you're at ArcGIS 10.1 SP1, you could use the [`arcpy.da.walk`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000023000000) function, passing in the `CadDrawing` option for `datatype`.

Otherwise you could use [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) to achieve the same thing, but you would need to implement logic to return only the file types you're interested in.

Comment: Quite odd - the same thing happens. The array is empty as if there were no CAD files. If I use `arcpy.da.walk` without specifying the data type, it now "sees" the CAD files.

Comment: I've resorted to using `os.walk` and restricting it to CAD extensions. I'll keep looking around to find out why it is not recognising the CAD files. Thanks